# GetControllerMapping returning an empty collection in WebApi2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working on creating a REST API.

I put something simple together that works using WebApi.

Then I discovered that I couldn't call it from outside of my domain, so I looked up what to do about that and found [this article on ASP.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors). The `config.EnableCors()` method doesn't appear to be available in WebApi but the article was written for WebApi2, so I uninstalled all of the packages and replaced them with their v2 counterparts.

Before making any CORS changes, I tried testing the API. I kept getting a 404 error. Debugging revealed that I am getting to the API OK, the problem is the call to `GetControllerMapping()`. With the WebApi v1 packages in place, this returned a collection of 5 controller. Having *only* replaced them with the v2 versions, the call returns an empty collection.

The Controller Section method is shown below...

```
    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var controllers = GetControllerMapping(); // <=== This is the line that returns an empty collection
        var routeData = request.GetRouteData();
        var controllerName = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];
        HttpControllerDescriptor result = null;

        if (!controllers.TryGetValue(controllerName, out result))
        {
            string version;
            if (!GetVersionFromMediaType(request, out version))
            {
                if (!GetVersionFromAcceptHeaderVersion(request, out version))
                {
                    if (!GetVersionFromHeader(request, out version))
                    {
                        if (!GetVersionFromQueryString(request, out version))
                        {
                            version = V_LATEST;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            HttpControllerDescriptor versionedDescriptor;

            var newName = string.Concat(controllerName, "V", version);
            if (controllers.TryGetValue(newName, out versionedDescriptor))
            {
                result = versionedDescriptor;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The various "GetVersion*" methods just return true/false depending on if they have found the relevant data and put tat data in the `out version` parameter.

FWIW, I can see the service registering the routes when it starts up.

Clearly, I've missed something but, so far, I've not found any documentation that might explain what it is.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting. Did you use any custom implementation for selecting controllers when it was working in v1? In your 404 response's body are you seeing an error something like "No type matching the controller name...".
Also what is the version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` nuget package that you are using for Web API2 as the article seems to be pointing to a pre-release pacakge.

Comment: @Kiran, yes. I was using a controller selection method, the same one I'm using now. The very first line of that method is `var controllers = GetControllerMapping();` and after this executes controllers is an empty list.

Comment: The exact output from the API call is `{"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8087/atlas/api/events/'.","messageDetail":"No controller was selected to handle this request."}`

Comment: The version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` is 5.0.0.0

Comment: Thanks...Can you share how your custom controller selector looks like as it depends on how you implemented it?

Comment: I've modified the Q above to include the code you asked for. Just to be clear, in this instance I'm using convention routing _not_ attribute routing.

Answer (score 1):

Check your "Controllers" if you have controller with same name even in different namespace this method will not return them.

Comment: If you have a suggestion, please add it as a comment and not an answer

Comment: you can try my code but it's need enhancement before production phase =>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462085/controller-versioning-in-web-api-2-using-url